How to prevent sorting of options in a SELECT control of Elementor Addon
I came across one issue with the Elementor while checking for the custom select dropdown
Below is my code, I am using with the custom widget
Value of key in a option are number or integer and not string
<?php
$this->add_control( 'Legacy', [
    'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
    'label' => 'Legacy',
    'options' => array_replace([
        '20' => esc_html__( 'Linear', 'elementor' ),
        '10' => esc_html__( 'Radial', 'elementor' ),
    ]),
] );
?>

The expected result in a select dropdown should be
Linear
Radial

Right?
But, when I see the result, it says
Radial
Linear

What I think is Elementor is filtering the options by key automatically before rendering
I am unable to find any filters or hooks associated with this
Do any of you have a solution to prevent this filtering of options and display as passed in the 'options' argument?

Elementor’s SELECT control auto sort option by their keys before rendering. Use empty array [] to preserve original order
<?php

$this->add_control( 'Legacy', [
    'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
    'label' => 'Legacy',
    'options' => array_replace(
        [], // Placeholder to preserve the original order
        [
            '20' => esc_html__( 'Linear', 'elementor' ),
            '10' => esc_html__( 'Radial', 'elementor' ),
        ]
    ),
] );

?>


Thank you, but this solution is not working.

Getting same result i.e. Radial followed by  Linear

At which point this "Elementor’s SELECT control auto sort option by their keys before rendering" is happening in Elementor plugin? Let me know if you have idea about this. Thank

Using array_merge instead of array_replace solved my issue. Thanks. You can update your answer
